# Sound not working on Elitebook 850 G5 on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04

I just decided to move to Linux, everything works awesome, loving it. Just sound stopped working and have been trying to diagnose since 8 hours. Here's what I know / tried / done:

Output device shows Dummy Output (when Ubuntu had installed, it showed Intel Tiger Lake - I'm using HP Elitebook 850 G5)

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (jammy)

Here is the hw-probe for my system: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=b01a9ac97f
I've a feeling the probe says what needs to be done, but I don't have enough experience to know how to do it.

I tried installing from: https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software
Installation / Build process goes fine until I hit

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop
```

`lspci -v` says

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255, IOMMU group 13
    Memory at 603f288000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Memory at 603f000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
```

`lshw -C multimedia` says

```
*-multimedia UNCLAIMED
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff memory:603f288000-603f28bfff memory:603f000000-603f0fffff
```

Please let me know if you need anything else, and thank you!

*Update: Explored around and moved to Pop!_OS, its amazing and everything works fine <3*

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out to be (it happened again when I was on Pop! OS after an update), an update of the kernel from 6.0.2 to 6.0.3. Going back to 6.0.2 fixed it. However this [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/yjpd8h/sound_not_working_after_upgrade_to_kernel_603/) recommended moving to 6.0.6 which also fixed it.

**Note: This is for Pop! OS, I'm not sure if it will work for Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-manage add popdev:linux-6.0.6
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).